# If a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has positive Lebesgue measure then it almost contains an interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

I want to show that if $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, then for every $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ there is an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $m(E \cap I) > (1 - \varepsilon) m(I)$. My proof is so easy that i doubt it's valid:
Notice that we only have to show it for $0 < m(E) < \infty$, because if $m(E) = \infty$ then there is a subset $E' \subseteq E$ such that $0 < m(E') < \infty$ and therefore for all $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ there exists an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $m(E \cap I) \geq m(E' \cap I) > (1 - \varepsilon) m(I)$. So suppose we have $0 < m(E) < \infty$ and fix $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. Now suppose by contradiction that for all intervals $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we have $m(E \cap I) \leq (1 - \varepsilon) m(I)$. Choose a sequence $\{ I_n \}_{n=0}^\infty$ of intervals such that $E \subseteq \cup_{n=0}^\infty I_n$ and $m(E) \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty
m(I_n) < m(E) + \frac{\varepsilon m(E)}{1 - \varepsilon}$. This implies that $m(E) = m(E \cap \cup_{n=0}^\infty I_n) = m(\cup_{n=0}^\infty (E \cap I_n)) \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty m(E \cap I_n) \leq (1 - \varepsilon) \sum_{n=0}^\infty m(I_n) < (1 - \varepsilon) \left( m(E) + \frac{\varepsilon m(E)}{1 - \varepsilon} \right) = m(E)$, contradiction. Is my proof of this claim valid?

Comment: Looks good to me